# complete:13: command not found: compdef

Tags: macos, terminal

When I open up terminal, the following message appears

```
complete:13: command not found: compdef
```

How can I fix it so that it disappears?

STEPS TAKEN
I have looked through similar questions posted on SO but have still not been able to solve the issue.

Comment: You should probably examine your `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc `. Sounds like it has some bad commands in it.

Comment: It looks like you're using zsh config files with Bash.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I am completely new at this but I got someone to help me and I will post the steps we took. Seems like the issue was related to your comments.

Answer (score 36):

For me it was the line below in the `.zshrc` file. For those that don't know you can find this as a hidden file ('Command' + 'Shift' + '.' to reveal) in your user directory. Remove or comment this line in a text editor or IDE of your choice.

```
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
source <(ng completion script)
```

Comment: That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 23):

This error came up after adding zsh auto-completion
[zsh autop complete](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/included/optional-kubectl-configs-zsh/)
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/included/optional-kubectl-configs-zsh/

If you get an error like: command not found: compdef, then add the following to the beginning of your `~/.zshrc` file:

```bash
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

Comment: I get the following when I do as you suggest:```zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]? ncompinit: initialization aborted
/dev/fd/12:18: command not found: compdef
user@machine ~ % compaudit
There are insecure directories:
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/share/zsh
```

Answer (score 19):

I'm on MacOs M1,
I had to add both of these lines to my .zshrc file

```
autoload -U +X compinit && compinit
autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit
```

before

```
complete -o nospace -C /opt/homebrew/bin/terraform terraform
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was using `terraform -install-autocomplete` to get to this error. My `/.zshrc` had the autoload line for bashcompinit but needed the line for compinit to resolve the error. thanks @spuder !

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem after installing Angular cli on my Mac. If your terminal got stuck and cannot run any commands. Follow these steps:

1. Find the .zshrc file.

Right-click Finder -> Go to Folder -> In the "Go to Folder" dialog box, enter ~ and go, this will take you to your home folder.

You could find the .zshrc here. Since it is a hidden file, you may need to type ('Command' + 'Shift' + '.' to reveal them.

2. Edit the .zshrc file.

If you see this line in you .zshrc file:

```
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
source <(ng completion script)
```

Comment it & save file.

```
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
# source <(ng completion script)
```

3. Reopen the terminal, the issue should be resolved.

Comment: Nice and complete, but doesn't actually fix the problem, just makes it go away. That's like fixing a hangnail by cutting off the arm. I'd downvote, but having been on the receiving end of a malicious downvote, I don't do that anymore unless it's REALLY bad.

Comment: The fix is to add ```autoload -U +X compinit && compinit
autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit ``` just above `source <(ng completion script)` by referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/76476988/494907 and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Open
nano .zshrc

Comment!

```
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
# source <(ng completion script)
```

Resolve

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [answer].

Comment: I tried to fix your formating, but since I do not get the phrasing of the prose either you need to review and probably fix what I broke.

Comment: That's like fixing a hangnail by cutting off the arm. I'd downvote, but having been on the receiving end of a malicious downvote, I don't do that anymore unless it's REALLY bad.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to [initialize completion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#:%7E:text=20.2.1%20Use%20of%20compinit) for the session which can be done in your `~/.zshrc` file.

Instead of commenting out the autocomplete install scripts you should add the following line above them:

```bash
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

Your autocomplete script could be a variety of things depending on what you have installed. It should look something like one of these:

```bash
source <(ng completion script)

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"

eval "$(_PROGRAM_NAME_COMPLETE=zsh_source programname)"
```

If that does not work, it's probably sourcing a bash completion script and you should add the following above them instead:

```bash
autoload -Uz compinit bashcompinit
compinit && bashcompinit
```

When you open a new terminal session the message should disappear.

Comment: I'm amazed so many 'answers' on here basically tell you to disable command line completion. Thank you for a more complete and better answer. Upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

I opened up my terminal and typed the below command to open up my zshrc

```
code ./zshrc
```

Inside that file I commented out the below command

```
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

This solved it.

Comment: That's like fixing a hangnail by cutting off the arm. I'd downvote, but having been on the receiving end of a malicious downvote, I don't do that anymore unless it's REALLY bad.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem after installing Angular cli on my macbook m1

Execute the following from the terminal

```
code .zshrc
```

remove the following lines from the file

```
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
source <(ng completion script)
```

save and reload the terminal, and the error should be gone

Comment: That's like fixing a hangnail by cutting off the arm. I'd downvote, but having been on the receiving end of a malicious downvote, I don't do that anymore unless it's REALLY bad.

Answer (score 2):

For me the following solved the issue:

My.zshrc (can be opened by `code ./zshrc`) looked like this:

```
# ...

autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit
complete -o nospace -C /opt/homebrew/bin/terraform terraform

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

I need to change the order of the two blocks:

```
# ...

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit
complete -o nospace -C /opt/homebrew/bin/terraform terraform
```

This solves for me. I have a strong feeling that the `\. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"` command has to be run before the `bashcompinit` command:)

Answer (score 1):

I opened up my Mac terminal and executed the command `open .zshrc` and deleted these lines `"//autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit` and `//complete -o nospace -C /usr/local/bin/terraform terraform"`. Closed and reopened the terminal and just like that my issue was fixed.

Comment: That's like fixing a hangnail by cutting off the arm. I'd downvote, but having been on the receiving end of a malicious downvote, I don't do that anymore unless it's REALLY bad.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the others, I had an issue with autocompletion loaded by my `.zshrc` file.

I commented out this line and did not have anymore issues:

```
source <(kubectl completion zsh)
```

I am on a M1 MacBook.

Comment: But you won't get command line completion working either ... it makes the error go away but it's like cutting off your hand to fix a hangnail.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, there are several possible things that could cause this issue. I first attempted the commenting out of:

```
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```

But this did not resolve my issue, the next one I found and determined was in my `.zshrc` and was the line:

```
eval "$(k3d completion zsh)"
```

Oddly enough it was completion specific to ZSH and not bash but still causing the issue and calling the old command.